# row.names returns duplicates error

Tags: r, time, time-series, dplyr

I'm trying to set a variable as row.names of a data frame, but it returns an error

```
    df <- structure(list(min = structure(c(1446356520, 1446356580, 1446356640, 
1446356700, 1446356760, 1446356820, 1446356940, 1446357000, 1446357300, 
1446357360, 1446357540, 1446357600, 1446357660, 1446357780, 1446357840, 
1446357900, 1446357960, 1446358020, 1446358080, 1446358140, 1446358200, 
1446358260, 1446358320, 1446358380, 1446358440, 1446358500, 1446358560, 
1446358620, 1446358680, 1446358740, 1446358800, 1446358860, 1446358920, 
1446358980, 1446359040, 1446359100, 1446359160, 1446359220, 1446359760, 
1446359880, 1446359940, 1446360060, 1446360120, 1446360360, 1446360420, 
1446360480, 1446360540, 1446360600, 1446360660, 1446360720, 1446360840, 
1446360900, 1446360960, 1446361020, 1446361080, 1446361200, 1446361320, 
1446361560, 1446361620, 1446361680, 1446362160, 1446362220, 1446362280, 
1446362340, 1446362400, 1446362640, 1446362700, 1446362760, 1446362820, 
1446363120, 1446363180, 1446363240, 1446363300, 1446363360, 1446363420, 
1446363540, 1446363600, 1446363660, 1446363720, 1446363780, 1446363840, 
1446363900, 1446364020, 1446364140, 1446364200, 1446364260, 1446364320, 
1446364380, 1446364440, 1446364500, 1446364620, 1446364680, 1446364740, 
1446364800, 1446364860, 1446364920, 1446364980, 1446365040, 1446365100, 
1446365160, 1446365220, 1446365280, 1446365340, 1446365520, 1446365640, 
1446365700, 1446365880, 1446365940, 1446366060, 1446366120, 1446366180, 
1446366300, 1446366360, 1446366420, 1446366480, 1446366540, 1446366600, 
1446366660, 1446366720, 1446366780, 1446366840, 1446366900, 1446366960, 
1446367020, 1446367080, 1446367200, 1446367260, 1446367320, 1446367380, 
1446367440, 1446367500, 1446367560, 1446367620, 1446367680, 1446367740, 
1446367800, 1446367860, 1446367920, 1446367980, 1446368100, 1446368160, 
1446368220, 1446368280, 1446368340, 1446369600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), x = c(38.2850437800097, 54.6280684533621, 55.4842107696813, 
46.0644593032863, 49.4597418424109, 67.6059490212197, 44.6591408267025, 
40.9899697115254, 46.4460720720815, 37.2086548602123, 54.76334410949, 
48.9405035847601, 60.1006445010298, 28.221375387737, 49.2167588238098, 
56.997559223317, 63.4367849698427, 70.2097104651127, 79.8544679993615, 
45.3944075132459, 53.0615320202733, 39.3464365328597, 50.5274454701418, 
40.8943620729146, 63.6003855024087, 41.6067031133194, 33.2946675552052, 
46.6969596813185, 72.985738950852, 49.8362417748977, 48.6141717886155, 
55.4703986810348, 43.5419227357279, 43.7494750187515, 49.9054121218426, 
51.6196553286232, 72.3487394802068, 52.4485049305326, 54.1602578645465, 
56.2643494139666, 43.170001534863, 52.8323026600894, 37.4930562823829, 
48.9783679998092, 49.1207138274192, 70.4579846636083, 57.6490734382511, 
49.0384606439069, 66.9599871437794, 45.0020747406631, 41.8363057389498, 
38.4311810840342, 63.304462970745, 43.2610691676051, 43.2241594286445, 
53.9000058263134, 52.2473967745082, 38.3869061176859, 48.9079249287781, 
45.0502439654172, 38.6740578528849, 57.2633733572339, 54.6139291029862, 
48.3780798947813, 60.0501215218032, 58.4530143378477, 49.9966803042729, 
52.937047691919, 37.8347709284913, 47.7037547819964, 54.1232625110556, 
67.8132244622227, 57.046304011728, 40.8481479063304, 52.693923262544, 
51.0930351552336, 58.6044673591969, 44.7805057335436, 48.0595039286341, 
56.3311502144779, 40.3912676416486, 40.1199017300942, 43.2738433299171, 
29.7610624275548, 66.6043723290772, 48.0339059048233, 59.4649478517923, 
46.8995582978353, 53.1532272217919, 50.7018392562179, 59.0968067529145, 
43.9992204100615, 62.5548335998761, 64.8837045725903, 51.7255765760984, 
59.0377897804391, 30.6299039891065, 65.0691311096482, 54.5919491685396, 
62.1950938865842, 54.4742288593181, 34.981450534196, 44.7609066993523, 
48.4715545487026, 70.2810182160341, 64.8685137415721, 58.5652136423351, 
53.4958596569791, 40.8242747306892, 45.044725681416, 41.6232263102073, 
65.0985772361349, 51.5889148542318, 43.4190260410788, 47.2852302055418, 
42.7945525824971, 33.9022227553083, 48.0476923042278, 52.9116947468539, 
49.7217620277756, 46.3398707481974, 43.1528074211376, 56.6380728715331, 
50.2753591551933, 52.2683423509245, 48.9858011860545, 49.2446548229646, 
56.9198828744485, 35.1703327690893, 49.7146330192441, 46.2564764171033, 
58.9263167057346, 48.9946134801825, 49.9835511780655, 50.0955046215364, 
58.6518769133605, 49.1342596036773, 65.4380107702529, 53.743631318482, 
58.3016438962537, 55.147327858343, 59.7113372780741, 69.4048321057239, 
64.9080137335855, 61.6057603530376)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("min", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, -145L))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
## Set column min as row.names:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
df <- tibble::column_to_rownames(df, var = "min")
```

Produces ther following error:

```
> df <- tibble::column_to_rownames(df, var = "min")
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘2015-11-01 01:00:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:02:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:06:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:07:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:08:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:18:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:19:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:25:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:26:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:27:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:32:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:33:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:34:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:35:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:36:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:37:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:40:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:41:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:42:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:43:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:44:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:45:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:47:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:49:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:50:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:51:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:52:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:53:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:55:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:57:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:58:00’, ‘2015-11-01 01:59:00’
```

So, I check for duplicates and NAs:

```
 df <- mutate(df, dup = duplicated((as.character(df$min))))
```

Check the number behind date format:

```
df <- mutate(df, min.numeric = as.numeric(min))
```

It appears seemingly different dates are treated as duplicates. I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: `any(duplicated(as.character(df$min)))
 # [1] TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I've revised my code above.  However, the problem stands: why are seemingly different datetimes treated as duplicates?